# Haskell: whileM_ variable scope?

Tags: haskell

How can I use a variable scoped in the `Bool` section of `whileM_` later in its body?

For example:

```
guess :: IO ()
guess = do
  putStrLn "Please input your guess."
  whileM_
    (do
      guess <- getLine
      return (guess /= "secret"))
    (do
      putStrLn ("You guessed: " ++ guess)
      putStrLn ("And " ++ guess ++ " is wrong."))
  putStrLn "Right - Bye..."
```

`guess` is not in scope in the second `do` block so unavailable for use.

How can I bring it into scope?

Thank you.

Comment: `whileM_` is definitely the wrong function for you! You can write this by hand using recursion pretty easily, or go searching for a function that fits your purpose better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`whileM_` doesn't have a built-in way of achieving this. That combinator is really a bit limiting; as dfeuer says you should probably just write the loop yourself using recursion. Or, use the loop construct that actually has support for this kind of information transfer:

```
guess :: IO ()
guess = do
  putStrLn "Please input your guess."
  whileJust_
    (do
      lastGuess <- getLine  -- don't use the name `guess` if that's already a global function name!
      return $ if lastGuess /= "secret"
                them Just lastGuess else Nothing )
    (\lastGuess -> do
      putStrLn $ "You guessed: " ++ lastGuess
      putStrLn $ "And " ++ lastGuess ++ " is wrong." )
  putStrLn "Right - Bye..."
```

However you *can* also communicate values between the condition- and execution parts of `whileM_`. Two options:

- Specifically in `IO`, you can always use [`IORef`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-IORef.html).

  ```
  guess :: IO ()
  guess = do
    putStrLn "Please input your guess."
    bestGuess <- newIORef ""
    whileM_
      (do lastGuess <- getLine
          writeIORef bestGuess lastGuess
          return $ lastGuess /= "secret" )
      (do lastGuess <- readIORef bestGuess
          putStrLn $ "You guessed: " ++ lastGuess
          putStrLn $ "And " ++ lasyGuess ++ " is wrong." )
    putStrLn "Right - Bye..."
  ```

  This is rather eschewed in Haskell – an `IORef` is basically a mutable variable – but sometimes it's sensible. Definitely not a good idea here.
- You can instead of `IO` use a dedicated monad with a pure-functional state variable. That requires [a monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#t:StateT). It's a slightly advanced technique, but for complex application can work out extremely well.

Comment: For this purpose, strict `StateT` seems more reasonable than lazy, but I think anything in that direction is overkill.

Comment: I was unaware of `whileJust_` and it seems the right tool for the job. Thank you for suggesting it.